# Persistant Checkbox Position

Tags: reactjs

i wanted to make checkbox position persistant when refresh page, see the picture below.

[Here's the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrafx.png)

and here's my code :

```
    <div className='checkboxTransaction ml-2'>
      <input
        id='radio1'
        name='radio'
        type='radio'
        defaultChecked={true}
        value='waiting'
       />
      <label htmlFor='radio1'>Menunggu Pembayaran</label>
    </div>
    <div className='checkboxTransaction ml-2'>
      <input
        id='radio2'
        name='radio'
        type='radio'
        value='waiting'
       />
      <label htmlFor='radio1'>Pesanan Dikirm</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: you will need to use `localStorage`

Comment: What does "persistent position" mean, and what have you tried? Do you mean physical position on screen, or checked value? Please share your relevant react code and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the state of the radio buttons to remain even after a refresh. For that purpose, you need to store the state of the radio buttons, for example, in the `localStorage`, and when rendering use the saved data to set the `defaultChecked` properly.

Here is a small sketch of the code that will probably show you what I mean.

```js
const fakeLocalStorage = {};

class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      testValue: fakeLocalStorage.test || 1
    };
  }
  
  onRadioChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({ testValue: value }, () => {
      fakeLocalStorage.test = value;
      
      console.log(fakeLocalStorage);
    });
  }
  
  renderInput(val) {
    return <input type='radio' name="test" onChange={this.onRadioChange} value={val} defaultChecked={this.state.testValue === val}  />;
  }
  
  render() {
    return (<div>
      <label for="test">Test</label>
      {this.renderInput(1)}
      {this.renderInput(2)}
      {this.renderInput(3)}
    </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```